# In Rails 3, is there a difference between = and assign_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say you're in your user controller and you want to change the name a @user based on some params you have available to you.

I want to know if there is any difference between the following:

```
@user.name = params[:user][:name]
```

or

```
@user.assign_attributes({:name=> params[:user][:name]})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A great way to figure out questions like this is to dive into the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails). I found the method in `activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb`[Check it out here.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb)

The `assign_attributes` method will actually just loop through the parameters given and sends the `:name=` message to your model. However, because you are possibly assigning many attributes, it takes into account mass-assignment precautions. (ie. make sure that the attribute is listed as `attr_accessible`).

Answer (score 3):

The `=` (e.g. `@user.name = params[:user][:name]`) directly calls the attribute setter with no security check. The `assign_attributes` checks security for the values passed in.

From the Rails API for assign_attributes:

> Allows you to set all the attributes for a particular mass-assignment
>   security role by passing in a hash of attributes with keys matching
>   the attribute names (which again matches the column names) and the
>   role name using the :as option.

[Source for assign_attributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32709ea41ed1ec2a89590e9bc6656c1ecd462d30/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L66)