# Rails "assign_attributes" not assigning nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-attributes

I have two models with the following structure:

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  has_one :credit_card
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit_card

  validates :credit_card, :presence => true
  validates_associated :credit_card
  ...
end

class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  belongs_to :wallet

  validates :card_number, :presence => true
  validates :expiration_date, :presence => true
  ...
end
```

I am testing the functionality of my application with RSpec, and I noticed something weird.  If I create a Hash with attributes that don't meet the validation criteria of my nested model (such as having a nil card_number), and then try to do an `update_attributes` call, then what I get returned in a Wallet object with an invalid CreditCard nested model, and the appropriate errors.  That is the correct, expected behavior.

If I take that same Hash though and run `assign_attributes`, and then `save` (which is all that update_attributes should be doing, then I get returned an invalid Wallet object with a completely nil nested object.  Why is that?  And how can I update all of the nested attribute values and check for errors without saving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - you don't need to `include ActiveModel::Validations` because they come with `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Second - yes `update_attributes` uses `assign_attributes` internally so basically it should work as expected.

If you don't have any `attr_accessible`, `attr_protected`, `with/without_protection` option and I assume you are creating proper hash with

```
{'credit_card_attributes' => {'card_number' => ''}}
```

then it looks like some kind of bug within rails. But at the same time I just checked it, and it seems that it works fine.

Above that if you want just to check validations without saving the object in tests, then just run

```
Wallet.new(hash_with_attributes).valid?
```

It should return proper wallet object with nested credit_card and errors on it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like Strong Params (Rails 4 feature) might be stripping out the nested attributes and since your validation fails without them you get redirected back to the edit page with errors and your credit card nested_attributes is now nil.

Perhaps this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532811/793330

Also save and update_attributes are not the same thing. Save will save the entire object whereas update will only change the items you pass to it that have changed. A slight difference but a difference none-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, assign_attributes skips security checks.

[In Rails 3, is there a difference between = and assign_attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854593/in-rails-3-is-there-a-difference-between-and-assign-attributes)

Comment: That link seems to say the opposite (that the equals sign is the function that skips security checks).  And I don't get why that would result in the behavior that I am seeing.