# How to use Rails 4 strong parameters with has_many :through association?

Tags: activerecord, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm having trouble getting a has_many :through association working with Rails 4's strong parameters. I have a model called `Checkout` and I need to select a person from the `Employee` model in the new checkout form. Checkouts and Employees are associated through an `Employment` model.

I'm getting this error when I try to create a new checkout:

```
NoMethodError in CheckoutsController#create
undefined method `employee' for #<Checkout:0x007ff4f8d07f88>
```

It seems that there's something wrong with either my create action, my checkout parameters or my new checkout form. Here's the create action:

```
  def create    
    @user = current_user
    @checkout = @user.checkouts.build(checkout_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @checkout.save
        format.html { redirect_to @checkout, notice: 'Checkout was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

My checkout params:

```
def checkout_params
      params.require(:checkout).permit(:job, :employee_ids, :shift, :date, :hours, :sales, :tips, :owed, :collected, :notes)
end
```

My new checkout form:

```
<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :employee %><br>
     <%= f.collection_select(:employee_ids, Employee.all.collect, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => "Please select"} ) %>
</div>
```

But I can't figure out what has changed with Rails 4 and strong parameters. In Rails 3 this type of association and form worked for me using attr_accessible instead of strong_parameters.

**Relevant Files**

Full Trace of the error:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/0cb9e2b539f9e1925a3d

models/checkout.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/012d6eae6b207beb147a

controllers/checkouts_controller.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a47466504b7783b31773

views/checkouts/_form.html.erb
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/ce0b4049b23e3d431f55

models/employee.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/46150bee3e6216fa29d1

controllers/employees_controller.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/04f3acdac0c9a678bca8

models/employment.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/6adad966dd48cb9d1b39

db/schema.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/36be318c677bad75b211

Comment: Having the same problem. I think the issue is that instead of just submitting the employee id, collection select wraps it in a hash. in your case "employee_ids"=>{"employee_id"=>"1","employee_id"=>"1"}.  i bet if you check your log, there will be a line that says "Unpermitted parameters:employee_ids" or similar.

Comment: I think that's the right direction. Here's my development log: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/cc2a71bef9a1e14fc5e6 Now how to fix this?

Comment: I updated my checkout_params to this https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a71981da605187d46d96, and now I am getting an `Unpermitted parameters` as you can see here: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/ef0a58695b7318f068ab

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Keep in mind that the name you give to your strong parameters (employees, employee_ids, etc.) is largely irrelevant because it depends on the name *you* choose to submit. Strong parameters work no "magic" based upon naming conventions.

The reason https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a71981da605187d46d96 is throwing an "Unpermitted parameter" error on 'employee_ids' is because it is expecting an **array** of scalar values, per https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters, not just a scalar value.

```
# If instead of:
... "employee_ids" => "1" ...
# You had:
... "employee_ids" => ["1"]
```

Then your strong parameters would work, specifically:

```
... { :employee_ids => [] } ...
```

Because it is receiving an array of scalar values instead of just a scalar value.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I actually did not need to nest the parameters. This is what ended up working for me:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def checkout_params
  params.require(:checkout).permit(:job, :shift, :employee_ids, :date, :hours, :sales, :tips, :owed, :collected, :notes)
end
```

Here is the combination of changes that worked.

- db/schema.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/32c792277de335aa54b8
- controllers/checkouts_controller.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/6e01ff8b86b1bdd078ed
- controllers/employees_controller.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/ad8d9f696b3121fd20e8
- models/checkout.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/6ffb28d54c6ea896bac5
- models/employee.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/85f53606494743e3d3b1
- models/employment.rb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/b9f9c8b750a23c8f3611
- views/checkouts/_form.html.erb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/d148d00345ad656fcd75
- views/checkouts/index.html.erb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/95f19b23ed121e40f73d
- views/checkouts/show.html.erb -
  https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/64ef85f66aa5d887489d

Still not quite understanding why this worked though.

Comment: Because you're not submitting a list of IDs...please refer to my previous explanation.

Comment: Oh so at the beginning of this thread I was attempting to submit `:employee_id` when it should have been `:employee_ids`. I never needed to nest the attributes, right?

Comment: Correct, naming aside, you never needed to nest the attributes since you were only submitting one scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

I can post the permit statement I use in one of my controllers.  This has a many to many association as well.  You nest the permit array.  Use the lookup association in your permit statement.  The only difference should be that yours won't be nested a third time.

In my case, the association 
Quote 
`has_many :quote_items`.

QuoteItems `has_many :quote_options, :through => quote_item_quote_options`.

In quotes_controller.rb

```
params.require(:quote).permit(:quote_date, :good_through, :quote_number, quote_items_attributes: [:id,:quote_id, :item_name, :material_id, quote_item_quote_options_attributes:[:quote_option_id,:quote_item_id,:qty,:_destroy,:id]])
```

Comment: Ok, based on that it seems that this should work for me `params.require(:checkout).permit(:job, :shift, :date, :hours, :sales, :tips, :owed, :collected, :notes, employees_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :number ])`, but I'm still getting an `undefined method "employee"` error. I've tried all of these variations, but still get that error: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/91ab475cf2a9e819724e. Based on the strong params documentation https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters, it seems like I could just use `{:employees => []}`, but that doesn't work either.