# How to update has_many :through association with strong parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to update the has_many :through association with strong parameters in Rails 4 without success.
This is my model :

```
User
  has_many :group_owner, :class_name => "Group"
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :memberships, :through => :group_memberships, :class_name => "Group"
end

Group
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :user_members
  has_many :members, :through => :user_members, :class_name => "User"
end
```

in the Group view (create/edit)

```
    <%= form_for(:group, :url => {:action => 'update', :group_id => @group.id}) do |f| %>   

        <th>New participant</th>
        <td><%= f.collection_select(:members, @users, :id, :first_name) %></td>

        <%= submit_tag("Update Group") %>
    <% end %>
```

Then, in the controller, I try to use strong parameters to save the new member in the DB:

```
def groupe_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:user_id, :group_name, members: [:id])
end
```

But the user is not saved in the DB, and I don't have any error message.
When I try to do

```
 group.members << user
```

via the ruby console, it succeeds.

I'm looking for a solution since few hours already. I've tried to understand the solution from this question ([How to use Rails 4 strong parameters with has_many :through association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436264/how-to-use-rails-4-strong-parameters-with-has-many-through-association)) but I'm still stuck.

I tried to check what is the value of *:members* variable in my controller :

```
 member_id = params[:members]
 flash[:notice] = "member id = #{member_id} !!"
```

and it is always empty :

```
 member id = !!
```

But, when I replaced in strong parameters :

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:user_id, :group_name, members: [:id])
end
```

by

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:user_id, :group_name, :members)
end
```

I get the following error :

```
undefined method `each' for "1":String

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GxCd==",
 "group"=>{"name"=>"G7",
 "members"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update Group",
 "group_id"=>"4"}
```

that show me that the *:members* variable is not empty !

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your incoming parameters, `params[:members]` does not exist - it's in `params[:group][:members]`. That's why your attempt to print `member_id` is not working. I suspect you meant to use `group_params[:members]`:

```
member_id = group_params[:members]
flash[:notice] = "member id = #{member_id} !!"
```

Your second problem is that `members` is not a list of objects, so specifying `members: [:id]` will not work. That expects parameters like

```
group: {
  members: [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ]
}
```

You're only passing in a list of IDs, so you want `members: []`, which expects a list of scalar values the way [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436264/how-to-use-rails-4-strong-parameters-with-has-many-through-association) describes.

Lastly, your `has_many` association is going to expect an attribute called `member_ids`, not `members`. So your final strong parameter definition should be:

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:user_id, :group_name, member_ids: [])
end
```

This will let you set the `Group`'s members via `group.member_ids = [1,2,3]` from the `has_many` relationship.

---

It looks like there might be an issue other than parameters, because your `User`s have many `Group`s through `group_memberships`, but your `Group`s have many `User`s through `user_members`. Unless you have other configuration compensating, you want to be using the same table there with `:user_id` and `:group_id` columns to get the relationship working correctly in both directions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation !