# rails associations between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

I've got two tables in my Postgres database: `categories` and `products`.

I have a one to many relationship defined, one category can have many products.

After I've defined these in the two models in Rails, is there something else I need to do to the tables?  I still have only the primary key that Rails defined when I set up each model separately.

Comment: Are you expecting to see a foreign key reference on the table the migrations create?

Comment: hmm, do I need to rake the db after I've added the associations in the active record files?  I haven't done that.  But, I would imagine I would need another key (foreign) that would point the products back to the categories.

Comment: I think you need to add foreign key: true on the column you want to make sure a foreign key is created in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257116/adding-foreign-key-to-a-rails-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a migration generator with the right parameters to set up the foreign key.

```
bin/rails generate migration AddCategoryRefToProducts category:references
```

This assumes you have a Product model and Category model with these associations:

```
#product.rb
belongs_to :category

#category.rb
has_many :products
```

Run `rake db:migrate` to complete the process

When you look at your db/migrate directory you will see a file that contains an add_reference line within a `def change` block.  Here's the reference for that method: [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).  The syntax for the standalone generator is [from the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)

Comment: Thanks!  I've just tried that.  Now I imagine my tables are connected.

Comment: Can I regenerate the products form to include this category automatically?   Or do I have to insert the dropdown manually?

Comment: Generally, the scaffold is used to create a prototype.  You generally update that prototype manually.  I don't think the intention was to allow you to make changes to the models and regenerate the views.

Comment: hmm, I've edited the _form for my products to include the category reference.  But the category reference for the product is not being written to the table.

Comment: Probably need to add to the permitted params in the controller.  For a has, many you need to permit `:product_id => []` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17532811/5586783